# Javafx loading FXML into TitledPane is blurred

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to loading a FXML into TitledPane. but it look like very blurred.
I dont know the reason.

My code include 2 files like below:

MainTitlePane.java

```
public class MainTitlePane extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override 
  public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    stage.setTitle("TitledPane");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 800);
    scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

    //Load AnchorPane from FXML file
    FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ChildPane.fxml"));
    AnchorPane childPane = (AnchorPane) loader1.load();

    //Add pane to TitledPane
    TitledPane tps1 = new TitledPane("First",childPane);         
    Accordion acc = new Accordion (tps1);   

    acc.setExpandedPane(tps1);

    //Add button outside of TitledPane
    Button btnTest = new Button("Button Direct");
    btnTest.setLayoutX(250.0);
    btnTest.setLayoutY(250.0);


    Group root = (Group)scene.getRoot();
    root.getChildren().addAll(acc, btnTest);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

and ChildPane.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
  <ScrollPane layoutX="673.0" prefHeight="380.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <content>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="189.0">
           <children>
              <Label layoutX="31.0" layoutY="22.0" text="Hello world" />
              <Button layoutX="49.0" layoutY="159.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit" />
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </content>
  </ScrollPane>

 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

When i run my code, the app look like the image below:

[image]

How I can fix my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason, i am using ScrollPane in ChildPane.fxml, the scroll bar will zoom the screen, i think that is the reason. 
It worked if i remove ScrollPane . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not quite clear what you want to achieve with this layout hierarchy. Anyway, simply remove the AnchorPane anchors or set them to 0.5 just like below.

```
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.5" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.5" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately an unresolved issue afaik. (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089499)

Text contents inside ScrollPane are getting blurry. There are couple workarounds;

1. As @wzberger mentioned, setting anchor constraints to 0.5 could solve this (I don't know why but it gets blurry again with 0.0 or 1.0)
2. Second solution would be via binding the ScrollPane width to AnchorPane

```
scrollPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty());
scrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty());
```

If you think it goes a bit over, you can substract from the width property

```
scrollPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty().subtract(100));
scrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty().subtract(100));
```